# Moving files with fs in electron.js

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using Electron and 'fs', and currently trying to move a file to another directory. I have no problems doing it so when I provide the file name (using fs.rename()) but I'm wondering if it can be done by not providing the destination filename and defaulting to the same filename as the destination.

The reason I want to do this, is because I want to move all the *.txt files in one directory to another. Is this possible??

Thanks!

Comment: There is no built-in node.js function to do it without constructing a filename for the destination.  You could launch a shell and do it in the shell by just specifying a target directory.

Comment: As @jfriend00 said, there's no built-in function in Node.js standard library to do so, but there's a third-party module called [shell.js](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) which provides a cross-platform implementation of unix shell commands on top of Node.js. So with shell.js, it'll be as easy as `mv('/path/to/filename', '/path/to/dest/dir/')`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll do as you recommended.

Comment: `fs-extra`'s [move](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/move.md#movesrc-dest-options-callback) is exactly what you need. (It also contains the built-in `fs`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A strict answer to your question would be: no it's not possible to do this with `fs` alone.

However I would recommend you to use [fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra), which has the [move](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/move.md) and [moveSync](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/move-sync.md) methods. Note that they don't support wildcards like `*.txt`, so you might need to iterate over the `txt` files using `fs.readdir`